# Creating a SOAP Header with WS-Addressing and WS-Security from scratch

Tags: c#, .net, soap, ws-security, ws-addressing

I am sending out a SOAP message from a windows service to an http endpoint (regular aspx page that will just accept the whole SOAP envelope). The overall operation is async, the actual response comes back at a later time. The nature of the setup (aspx page receiving message) means I cannot have a service reference in my project.

The SOAP header has to include WS-Addressing and WS-Security. What I need to do is basically construct the SOAP envelope, but more specifically the SOAP header from scratch and then compose the SOAP envelope before sending it.

Its Friday afternoon, I am frazzled and I am struggling to get to grips with getting this going. Using .net3.5/C#, how do I construct a SOAP header with the addressing and security from scratch?

Comment: I have made some progress with this. After refocusing, I made freinds with the Microsoft.Web.Services3 namespace.

But I do have a new issues. When I create the Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Utility.Timestamp and Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Tokens.UsernameToken nodes, I cannot create a Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Security object properly. I can cheate and create a <wsse:Security> node and add the Timestamp and UsernameToken to that. It all seems improper though.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried these guides:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms824647.aspx

Regards, Chris.